# Server responds by "text/html" to a "text/css" request

Tags: python, css, django, apache

**PROBLEM:** When I try to access the web page (localhost/mysite/admin), all goes well, except the CSS files which my server can't deliver !!

[I got a **500 Internal Server Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VNcT.png)

[By investigating the problem, I found that the server returns a **text/html** instead of **text/css**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4wTn.png)

**Apache 2.4.23
 / mod_wsgi 4.5.5
 / Python 3.4.2
 / Django 1.8
on Linux Debian (64-bit)**

Additional informations:

This is my **settings.py** file

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '##################################################'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/django-projects/mysite/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The lines wich are appended to the httpd.conf (Apache HTTP Server)

```
# Enable access for Django website mysite
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /var/www/django-projects/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=mysite
WSGIScriptAlias /static /var/www/django-projects/mysite/static process-group=mysite
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django-projects/mysite:/home/ibrahim/.virtualenvs/django-1.8/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/django-projects/mysite:/home/ibrahim/.virtualenvs/django-1.8/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
<Directory /var/www/django-projects/mysite>
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymLinks
    ServerSignature On
</Directory>
```

Project structure:

```
- mysite
    - mysite
        + __pycache__
          __init__.py
          settings.py
          urls.py
          wsgi.py
    - polls
        + __pycache__
        + migrations
          __init__.py
          admin.py
          models.py
          tests.py
          views.py
    - static
        - admin
            - css
                base.css
                ........
            + img
            + js
    + templates
    .schema
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

Note that the file `/usr/local/apache2/conf/mime.types` include the following line: `text/css       css`

Comment: Is your server serving other static files? JS and the images?

Comment: Did you `python manage.py collectstatic`? I assume you did, that's why your other static files are being served, but did you by any means add your css at a later point of time and didn't do `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: All the static files are imported to the project by using the command `python manage.py collectstatic` , I haven't touched any thing !

Answer (score 0):

@Ankush Raghuvanshi: 
Yes, it serves all kind of files except CSS !
Also, when I us the built-in development server (which I run by using the command `python manage.py runserver` ): these CSS files works fine on my website.