# Refused to apply style because MIME type is not supported

Tags: html, css, ruby, mime-types, mime

I keep getting an error that says that the MIME type ('text/html') isn't executable or not a supported stylesheet MIME type and that strict MIME checking is enabled.

[image: Error shown]

My code that links it is

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This is how the template is supposed to look

[image: Template]

However, this is what it looks like

[image: Template]

Do I need to change text/html into something else?

```
accepts: {
        "*": allTypes,
        text: "text/plain",
        html: "text/html",
        xml: "application/xml, text/xml",
        json: "application/json, text/javascript"
    },
```

Sinatra is telling me to do this

[image: this]

but I've tried and it doesn't work

Is there anything I should change or add to my code so that the css works?

Comment: Can you include the error *text* in the body of your question? Images, especially links to images, are problematic for some people and can't be indexed properly, meaning that other people looking for the same error can't find this question and any answers it might have.

Comment: This seems to be a server-side issue, your CSS is being served up as HTML. On servers like Apache `httpd` this requires identifying `.css` files with the right MIME type (`text/css`).

Comment: Related: [css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43532944/1016716) and [yii2 css file won't load because it's MIME type text/html is not text/css on windows7 apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41769001/1016716) and [Server responds by “text/html” to a “text/css” request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39241820/1016716) and [Page CSS will not load - simple html and js file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45534501/1016716) and [.js and .css files are loading as text/html in my JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11480347/1016716)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you'd want `text/css` for your stylesheets, and `application/javascript` for the JS files.

According to the sinatra docs, the incoming request object can be accessed from the request level

```
get '/foo' do
  t = %w[text/css text/html application/javascript]
  request.accept              # ['text/html', '*/*']
  request.accept? 'text/xml'  # true
  request.preferred_type(t)   # 'text/html'
end
```