# strict MIME checking is enabled error

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I have a node js project and added a template for the admin are. on my local server it show everything is ok but when i push it to my web server on vultr it does not load the admin page and show several errors in the console. these errors are not shown in the dev systems web browser console.

The errors are:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://www.skillbuild.pro/admin/assets/node_modules/morrisjs/morris.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

it also shows several js files are not fount (404 error) whereas these files exist in the relevant folder.

Following is my head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> {{!--
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> --}}
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../assets/images/favicon.png">
    <title>Elite Admin Template - The Ultimate Multipurpose admin template</title>
    <!-- This page CSS -->
    <!-- chartist CSS -->
    <link href="/admin/assets/node_modules/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--Toaster Popup message CSS -->
    <link href="/admin/assets/node_modules/toast-master/css/jquery.toast.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Morris CSS -->
    <link href="/admin/assets/node_modules/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/admin/dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Dashboard 1 Page CSS -->
    <link href="/admin/dist/css/pages/dashboard1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

and these are my footer section where the js files are called:

```
<!-- All Jquery -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap popper Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/popper/popper.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
<script src="/admin/dist/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!--Wave Effects -->
<script src="/admin/dist/js/waves.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!--Menu sidebar -->
<script src="/admin/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!--Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="/admin/dist/js/custom.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- This page plugins -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!--morris JavaScript -->

<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/raphael/raphael-min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/morrisjs/morris.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- Popup message jquery -->
<script src="/admin/assets/node_modules/toast-master/js/jquery.toast.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="/admin/dist/js/dashboard1.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

in my server.js file I have defined the path:

```
// Use path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

for some reason on the local server it shows everything and there are no errors, but when I push it to my web server which is a vps and I am using pm2 for node process manager, it shows the errors in the browser and does not load the admin page.

Please help, this is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Do any of the links in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691921/refused-to-apply-style-because-mime-type-is-not-supported#comment88404234_50691921) help?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I am now running any web server like apache or nginx. Instead I am running pm2 on a vps.